# How to set Trusted Web Activities content "edge-to-edge" (behind the status bar)

Tags: android, kotlin, statusbar, trusted-web-activity

How to set Trusted Web Activity content "edge-to-edge" (behind the status bar)?

What is required and what have I tried:
https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/edge-to-edge
It works fine for the native code. But when com.google.androidbrowserhelper.trusted.LauncherActivity started - the content is drawn below the status bar.

PS Immersive mode is not suitable) Although it works with TWA.

Answer (score 0):

AFAICT, this isn't supported. [Bubblewrap supports 3 display modes](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/bubblewrap/blob/main/packages/core/src/lib/TwaManifest.ts#L42): standalone, fullscreen, and fullscreen-sticky.

- Standalone is the default which shows status bar.
- Fullscreen is the immersive mode that doesn't have the status bar, but as you mention, isn't suitable for your app.
- Fullscreen sticky is similar to fullscreen/immersive, but if the user swipes the edge of the screen, the system bars will be semi-transparent and the swipe gesture will be passed to your app. Useful for drawing apps or games where lots of swiping is involed.

None of those modes sound like what you want. The closest is fullscreen (immersive) mode. Maybe you could clarify why fullscreen/immersive mode doesn't work for you.